# No files to submit even after I add them to perforce changlist

Tags: perforce, p4python

I get a changelist number and I am able to add the files to the changelist

```
>>> createdCLNumber
'1157545'
>>> p4.run_add("-c", createdCLNumber, "/Users/ciasto/ciasto_piekarz/sandbox/main/upgrade_tools/upgrade_gitlab")
['//depot/td/main/bin/upgrade_gitlab#1 - currently opened for add']
```

but when I try to submit them I get the error.

```
>>> p4.run_submit(changeList)
P4.P4Exception: [P4#run] Errors during command execution( "p4 submit -i" )

        [Error]: 'No files to submit.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit a numbered changelist (implied by the fact that you used `p4 add -c CHANGELIST`), do:

```
p4 submit -c CHANGELIST
```

See `p4 help submit`:

```
submit -- Submit open files to the depot

p4 submit [-Af -r -s -f option --noretransfer 0|1]
p4 submit [-Af -r -s -f option] file
p4 submit [-Af -r -f option] -d description
p4 submit [-Af -r -f option] -d description file
p4 submit [-Af -r -f option --noretransfer 0|1] -c changelist#
p4 submit -e shelvedChange#
p4 submit -i [-Af -r -s -f option]
          --parallel=threads=N[,batch=N][,min=N]
```

If you only specify a single argument, it's interpreted as a file path:

```
p4 submit [options] file
```

To specify a changelist you want this form:

```
p4 submit [options] -c changelist#
```

Comment: if this works I am going to wrap this in `python.Subprocess` instead of using `p4python` api

Comment: Note that the P4Python version would just be `p4.run_submit("-c", changeList)`.  Everything in P4Python just works exactly like the CLI commands.

Comment: Lets not confuse few things , when I added files to p4 I ran `p4.run_add("-c", createdCLNumber, [file/path])` which I believe is equivalent to `p4 add -c 1157545 /Users/ciasto/ciasto_piekarz/sandbox/main/upgrade_tools/upgrade_gitlab` . later when we submit its only the number passed to p4. i.e. `p4 submit -c 1157545`

inbetween add and submit I did one more thing I didnt found on documentaiton examples, i.e. `changeList['Files'] = ["file/path/file/on/disk"]` then I ran submit. this changeList was what I passed to `p4.save_change` to get the changelistNumber

Comment: That doesn't actually work because you didn't run the command that updates the changelist.  But you're also making this way too complicated; you don't need a numbered changelist for this workflow at all.

Comment: Protip: instead of posting five different questions about five different subsets of a problem you've overcomplicated, you might be able to post a single question about the thing you're actually trying to do (e.g. "I am trying to add a file") and get the simple solution.  :)

Comment: I just want you to be the future Lead or moderator  at  Stackoverflow.

 PS: with the changelist number it worked for me